# Sign of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Someone could compute the sign of the following series ?

\begin{equation} \underset{k > 0}{\sum} \frac{\sin (kx)}{k} \end{equation}

I expect that is the same as the first term $\sin x$ because of the pseudo terms-alternate property of the serie, but it's not clear. 
If you have an idea, it would be nice.

Thanx for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your series is the Fourier-Series of the $2\pi$-peridodic extension of the function
$$
f(x):=\frac{\pi-x}{2}
$$
defined on $[0,2\pi]$, hence the sign will depend on $x$…
EDIT:
Thus your statement
$$\operatorname{sgn}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin (kx)}{k}\right)=\operatorname{sgn}(\sin x)$$
is correct.

Comment: A more difficult to prove fact is: all the partial sums have the sign of $\sin x$, this being Fejér-Jackson-Gronwall's inequality.

Comment: Is there exist a book or some lectures where I could find this inequality ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{k}=\Im\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}}{k}=-\Im\ln\left(1-e^{ix}\right)$$
where we use Taylor series of $\ln(1-x)$. Now, we use [the principal value of complex logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value). We get
$$\ln\left(1-e^{ix}\right)=\ln\left(1-\cos x-i\sin x\right)=\ln\sqrt{(1-\cos x)^2+\sin^2x}-i\arctan\left(\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}\right)$$
Hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{k}=-\Im\ln\left(1-e^{ix}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}\right)=\arctan\left(\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$
where we use identities
$$\sin x=2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
and
$$\cos x=2\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1$$
Using identity
$$\arctan\left(x\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin kx}{k}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$$