# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin kx}{x}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ for $0\le x\le 2\pi$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, fourier-series

Refer to this OP: [Sign of a series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926066/sign-of-a-series), we have the following equation

> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin kx}{k}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}
> \end{equation}

defined for $0\le x\le 2\pi$.

---

Here is my attempt to prove it:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin kx}{k}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int\cos kx\,dx\\
&=\int\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos kx\right)\,dx\\
&=\int\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}{2}\right)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{ix}}+\frac{1}{1-e^{-ix}}\right)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}x+C
\end{align}
Here is the problem:

To get the value of $C$, let $x=0$ and I get $C=0$, but if I let $x=\pi$ I get $C=-\frac{\pi}{2}$. Similarly, if I I let $x=2\pi$ I get $C=-\pi$. Where am I doing it wrongly? Could you please point out my mistake and guide me to prove the above equation? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: when u substituted sinkx/k , you limits on the integral were already decided so constant term wont come .

Comment: You should know better than using displaystyle math in question titles.

Comment: I would say $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos kx$ does not converge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^n}n=-\ln(1-t).~$ Now [let](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) $t=e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, and use [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula).

Comment: Using your hint, I get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{n}=\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}$$

Comment: I also get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{n}=\frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-e^{ix}}{1-e^{-ix}}\right)$$

Comment: @V-Moy: **No!** You should get $\arctan\dfrac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}$. But $\sin x=2\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2$, and $\dfrac{1-\cos x}2=\sin^2\dfrac x2$, so your expression becomes $\arctan\cot\dfrac x2$, which is obviously $\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac x2$.

Comment: Waawww!! Sorry Mr. Lucian, I forgot to take its inverse tangent of the argument. +1